# WildFly 10 with WebSphere MQ 9 : onMessage MDB deploy error

Tags: java, ibm-mq, wildfly-10

> 1. I have an MDB for consuming a message of a Queue, on Jboss EAP 7.0.6 GA, IBM MQ 9

```
    package com.ryzorbent.demo.jms;

    import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
    import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
    import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
    import javax.jms.JMSException;

    import javax.jms.Message;
    import javax.jms.MessageListener;
    import javax.jms.TextMessage;

    import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.ResourceAdapter;

    @MessageDriven(name="EFRSTestMDB", activationConfig = {
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "hostName", propertyValue = "localhost"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "port", propertyValue = "1414"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "channel", propertyValue = "SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "queueManager", propertyValue = "EFRS_UAT"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/queue/QUEUE"),
            @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "transportType", propertyValue = "CLIENT")
        })

    @ResourceAdapter(value = "wmq.jmsra.rar")
    //@TransactionAttribute(value = "NoTransaction")

    public class EFRSTestMDB implements MessageListener {


        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message inMessage) {
            TextMessage message = (TextMessage)inMessage;
            try {
                System.out.println(String.format("Hello, %s", message.getText()));
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

> 2. I copied the **wmq.jmsra.rar** into the ../standalone/deployments
> 3. Added the resource-adapters subsystem for the queues, channels, etc into the standalone-full.xml
> 4. But i get the below error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/ryzorbent/demo/jms/EFRSTestMDB (Module "deployment.TestJbossMDB.jar:main" from Service Module Loader): javax/jms/MessageListener
```

Answer (score 1):

The `wmq.jmsra.rar` does not contain the JMS API classes like `javax/jms/MessageListener` from your error. In [Limitations and Known Problems](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuring_messaging/resource_adapters#the_limitations_and_known_problems_for_WebSphere_mq) it says:

> The deployment of the IBM WebSphere® MQ 7.5 resource adapter does not load the javax.jms.api module for your deployment. It also does not provide support for the new Jave EE 7 annotations like @JMSConnectionFactoryDefinitions, @JMSDestinationDefinition. It is necessary to have the messaging-activemq subsystem in the configuration to enable it. If you do not want the JBoss EAP messaging server to be started, add an empty messaging-activemq subsystem.

So you have to add the JMS api jars as well like described above.

Comment: I have added `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">` in the standalone-full.xml file

>But the ** Messaging - ActiveMQ ** does **not** appear under **Subsystems** 
>I am using IBM MQ version 8 of the `wmq.jmsra.rar`

Comment: In [Messaging configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Messaging+configuration), chapter Required Extension it is written how to get this subsystem. Did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

hWhen using IBM MQ messaging, always start with a "full" server configuration file such as standalone-full.xml.  The "full" configuration files include JMS messaging.

As a side note, I see that your activation spec has:

```
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "useJNDI", propertyValue = "false"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/queue/QUEUE"),
```

So you have useJNDI to false, but then you have destination that sure looks like a JNDI name.  When you have useJNDI set to false, the destination name is the name of the queue on the IBM MQ side - normally in all caps, much like your queue manager and channel.